# How can i change orientation of apk , locked in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

When i change the screen orientation in Manifest.xml from landscape to reverseLandscape then the app(game) run in reverseLandscape for only 1 second and after that it again shift to landscape mode automatically,i want it to run in reverselandscape for the whole time

Answer (score 0):

U should use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Define it inside your activity in the AndroidManifest. Like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Mainactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```